# How to load a ModelingPackage (DSL-Tools) asynchronously in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: vsix, vs-extensibility, vsx, dsl-tools

I have a DSL-tools project where I use `[ProvideAutoLoad]` because it adds a set of menu commands to Visual Studio to allow the user to transform code (we have lots of text templates), and few other things.

Since VS2019 does [not allow to autoload sync packages anymore](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/updates-to-synchronous-autoload-of-extensions-in-visual-studio-2019/), I get that annoying warnings even when the option to allow autoload is on.

Apparently Microsoft has no plans to provide an async version of `ModelingPackage` (I am in fact begining to question if their not in the way to descontinue DSL-tools alltogether).

As anyone found a way of working around this?

I have tried to use another package - built as `AsyncPackage` - so that one would load my DSL-tools package on `InitializeAsync()` but I end up with all sorts of exceptions using the `IVsShell` service.

```
protected override async Task InitializeAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, IProgress<VSShell.ServiceProgressData> progress)
{
    // Default behavior

    await base.InitializeAsync(cancellationToken, progress).ConfigureAwait(false);

    // Load the service designer package

    this.EnsureDesignerPackage();

    // Switche to the UI thread

    await JoinableTaskFactory.SwitchToMainThreadAsync(cancellationToken);

    // Menu commands

    this.InitializeMenuCommands();
}

private void EnsureDesignerPackage()
{
    // Package already loaded?

    if (!this.IsDesignerPackageLoaded())
    {
        this.LoadDesignerPackage();
    }
}

private bool IsDesignerPackageLoaded()
{
    // Package identifier

    Guid packageId = new Guid(GlobalConstants.ServiceDesignerPackageId);

    // Is loaded?

    IVsShell service = this.VsShellService;

    int hr = this.VsShellService.IsPackageLoaded(ref packageId, out IVsPackage package);
    if (ErrorHandler.Succeeded(hr) && package != null)
    {
        return true;
    }

    // Default result

    return false;
}

private void LoadDesignerPackage()
{
    // Package identifier

    Guid packageId = new Guid(GlobalConstants.ServiceDesignerPackageId);

    // Not loaded?

    int hr = this.VsShellService.IsPackageLoaded(ref packageId, out IVsPackage package);
    if (hr != VSConstants.S_OK || package == null)
    {
        // Load

        hr = this.VsShellService.LoadPackage(ref packageId, out package);
        if (ErrorHandler.Failed(hr))
        {
            string message = "Service designer loading failed: {0}.".Format().With(hr);
            this.ShowException(message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: IMHO, DSL tools has always been on the edge of being dropped, with every VS release... I has not really evolved for all these years, it just continues to work because most of VS still supports 20 years old interfaces. I sure wouldn't bet on this for the long term, but you should ask Microsoft about that (why not add comments to Mads Kristensen's blog)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just happened to walk a customer through this same scenario earlier today. Unfortunately, the last time I asked there were no current plans to update the underlying DSL framework to leverage AsyncPackage or similar. I saw you already logged a suggestion in the [dev community site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57608183/how-to-load-a-modelingpackage-dsl-tools-asynchronously-in-visual-studio-2019), and just up voted and added my own $.02. I would encourage anyone hitting this to up vote this suggestion linked above.

To add support for Async Load, to your DSL Package object, you'll want to add a reference the Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.14.0.DesignTime.dll assembly, and then edit your Package.tt file, to add a VSShell.PackageRegistration attribute with AllowsBackgroundLoading set to true, and implement the IAsyncLoadablePackageInitialize interface on that same class. For example:

```
namespace <#= CodeGenerationUtilities.GetPackageNamespace(this.Dsl) #>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Double-derived class to allow easier code customization.
    /// </summary>
    [VSShell::ProvideMenuResource("1000.ctmenu", 1)]
    [VSShell::ProvideToolboxItems(1)]
    [VSShell::PackageRegistration(AllowsBackgroundLoading = true)]
    [global::Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.VSHost.ProvideDirectiveProcessor(typeof(global::<#= this.Dsl.Namespace #>.<#= directiveName #>DirectiveProcessor), global::<#= this.Dsl.Namespace #>.<#= directiveName #>DirectiveProcessor.<#= directiveName #>DirectiveProcessorName, "A directive processor that provides access to <#= directiveName #> files")]
    [global::System.Runtime.InteropServices.Guid(Constants.<#= dslName #>PackageId)]
    internal sealed partial class <#= dslName #>Package : <#= dslName #>PackageBase, VSShellInterop.IAsyncLoadablePackageInitialize
    {
        public VSShellInterop.IVsTask Initialize(VSShellInterop.IAsyncServiceProvider pServiceProvider, VSShellInterop.IProfferAsyncService pProfferService, VSShellInterop.IAsyncProgressCallback pProgressCallback)
        {
            // do async initialization here
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Sincerely,

Comment: Thank you for your idea!